# hide or remove checkbox which is on colorbox popup after selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, colorbox

I have dropdown list and checkbox popup(colorbox popup) list in which data comes from `complaint.csv` file.

**complaint.csv File**

```
1,complaint type 1
2,complaint type 2
3,complaint type 3
etc...
```

I want to hide/remove checkbox from the popup checkbox list when item is selected from dropdown. e.g. if 'complaint type 1' is selected from dropdown then 'complaint type 1' from checkbox list should be removed/hide.

Here is some code.

**PHP code:**

```
<label class="question-name" ng-class="{error:hasError()}">
  <span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="question.nameHiddenOnMobile">
    Chief Complaint
  </span>
  <span class="icon-required" ng-show="question.required"></span>
</label>

<select name="Language.PrimarySpoken" ng-hide="showAddAnswer"
        ng-model="question.response.value" 
        ng-options="a.text as a.getText() for a in question.answers.items"
        id="Language.PrimarySpoken" ng-value="a.text" class="input-wide" 
        ng-class="{error:hasError()}"  onchange="changeEventHandler(event);">
  <option class="hidden" disabled="disabled" value=""></option>

  <?php
    $file_handle = fopen("../complaint.csv", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
      $lines_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    foreach ( $lines_of_text as $line_of_text): 
  ?>
      <option value="<?php print $line_of_text[1]; ?>">
        <?php print $line_of_text[1]; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br/> <br/>

    <label class="question-name" ng-class="{error:hasError()}">
      <span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="question.nameHiddenOnMobile">
        Additional Complaint
      </span>
      <span class="icon-required" ng-show="question.required"></span>
    </label>

    <div class="form-row added ng-binding" ng-bind-html="question.getText()" id="text" ></div>
    <div class="form-row addlink ng-binding" 
         ng-bind-html="question.getText()">
      <em><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">+ Add/Edit</a></em>
    </div>

    <div style='display:none'>
      <div id='inline_content' style='padding:25px; background:#fff; font-size: 17px;'>

        <form action="" id="popup_form">

       <?php

        // Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------        
        define('numcols',4);  // set the number of columns here
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../complaint.csv'));
        $numcsv = count($csv);
        $linespercol = floor($numcsv / numcols);
        $remainder   = ($numcsv % numcols);
        // Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------        


        // The n-column table --------------------------------------------------
        echo '<div class="table">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '   <div class="column">'.PHP_EOL;

        $lines = 0;
        $lpc   = $linespercol;
        if ($remainder>0) { $lpc++; $remainder--; }
        foreach($csv as $item) {
            $lines++;
            if ($lines>$lpc) {
                echo '   </div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="column">'.PHP_EOL;
                $lines = 1;
                $lpc   = $linespercol;
                if ($remainder>0) { $lpc++; $remainder--; }
            }
            echo '      <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox'.$item[0].'" style="font-size:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="'.$item[1].'" id="checkbox'.$item[0].'" data-toggle="checkbox">'
                            .$item[1].
                        '</label><br />';
        }
        echo '   </div>'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
        // The n-column table --------------------------------------------------


    ?>
         <br/>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="update" 
                class="button button-orange" 
                style="width: 90px; margin-top: 450px; margin-left:-1062px;" 
                value="Update">
         <input type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" 
                class="button button-orange" 
                style="width: 90px; background-color:#36606e;" 
                value="Cancel">

        </form>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeEventHandler(event) {
        $('.inline').colorbox({onLoad: function() {
            //  alert('You have ' + event.target.value + ' complaint.');
            $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + event.target.value + ']').parent().hide();
        }});
    }
</script>
```

In above **JS code** I am getting `alert` of selected value from dropdown (the line of `alert` which is commented) but the checkbox item having that selected value is not removing somehow.(for this line `$('input[type=checkbox][value=' + event.target.value + ']').parent().hide();` , I am getting just loading icon on popup)

Can anyone please tell me how should I do that?

**Note:** I am reading data from complaint.csv file for both dropdown list and checkbox popup list in php as shown in above code.

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox][value=' + event.target.value + ']').parent().hide();` remove `.parent()`

Comment: @guradio By removing `.parent()`popup is just showing loading icon.

Comment: what is the value ??

Comment: @Yo Yo value of dropdown select option `$line_of_text[1];` and value of checkbox input element `.$item[1]` is same which is getting from complaint.csv file.

Comment: @kiran .. i mean its a integer or char ?

Comment: @Yo Yo Its char value. e.g. 'complaint type 1' etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make following changes and check

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value="' + event.target.value+ '"]').parent().hide();
```

Comment: yeah, its working now. But its giving me the empty space for the item which is removed. Is there any way so that next item will take its space?

Comment: Great that it worked !! I wont mind if you accept the answer .. and regarding "next item taking its place" ..as far as i know you need to make cahnges in css .. and it has to be `position:relative`

Comment: Where that css change should be?

Comment: it should, but its not working for empty space. I had tried `display` property of css also there. but no use. :(

Comment: can i see your html .. is it on server ??